# Ubuntu / NGINX - Can't change ownership or permissions of certain directories and files

Tags: linux, nginx, permissions

I have some folders on a ubuntu server running Nginx with the following permissions & groups:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data some_folder
```

I am trying to delete these within a deployment script, as a user called `deploy`. This user is in the `www-data` group.

I know that to delete these folders, I need group write permissions (which I currently don't), however the deploy user doesn't have the permissions to set this. I've tried `chmod 775 some_folder` and also setting the deploy user as the owner with `chown deploy some_folder`, but I always get this error:

```
chown: changing ownership/permissions of 'some_folder/': Operation not permitted
```

How can I delete these folders without using `sudo`?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What would be the point of ownership and permissions if an unprivileged user could change them?

Comment: Yep fair enough. I was hoping that a user in the folder's group had the ability to change permissions, but I get why that wouldn't make sense. Reason I was asking is because there are some cache files I need to delete when deploying, however I've literally just realised there is a command to clear the cache that will remove the need for this entirely